# Terraform array variable to string from vault

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-gcp, vault, hashicorp

I want to use an array to be used as a secret in the vault,
but the required value is not as expected it carries the backslash `\` character after being output in terraform. i tried to use trim in terraform but it just erased some backslashes and the value can't be used

[image: secret iplist from vault ui]
secret iplist from vault ui

[image: result outputs from terraform]
result outputs from terraform

output trim code
`trim(nonsensitive(data.secret.secret_data.data["iplist"]) , "\"")`

[image: result outputs after using trim]
result outputs after using trim

can I use the value in the form of an array without the backslash `\` and in the form of a list of strings ?

Comment: What Terraform code are you using to construct the secret string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved a similar result by using [`format`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/format) with `%v` which formats arrays, I understood that you are getting your value like the following local variable:

```
locals {
  ips = "\"10.10.1.0/24\",\"10.10.2.0/24\",\"10.10.1.1/32\""
}
```

You only need the square brackets `[]` to form an array string, then pass it to `format`

```
output "ips" {
  value = format("%v", "[${local.ips}]")
}
```

And this was the result

```
  + ips = jsonencode(
        [
          + "10.10.1.0/24",
          + "10.10.2.0/24",
          + "10.10.1.1/32",
        ]
    )
```

The previous plan result showed [`jsonencode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode) since it printed a valid JSON array so I wanted to try it directly, and it worked:

```
output "ips" {
  value = jsondecode("[${local.ips}]")
}
```

The plan:

```
  + ips = [
      + "10.10.1.0/24",
      + "10.10.2.0/24",
      + "10.10.1.1/32",
    ]
```